# Change Color of Everything on Screen - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a pause button/method(not the greatest but it works).  Currently, I am changing the opacity of EVERYTHING on screen when it is paused which is not what I want to do but it works(and is a pain).  Does anyone have a better way of changing the brightness of everything on screen at the same time?

E.G.
when you pause "Angry Birds"(only game I could think of at the moment) the main scene has a transparent black overlay on it.

Here is my Code

```
-(void) Pause:(ccTime)delta
{
    Bag.opacity = 150;
    ScoreH.opacity = 150;
    TimerH.opacity = 150;
    leftB.opacity = 150;
    rightB.opacity = 150;
    bg.opacity = 150;
    scoreLabel.opacity = 150;
    timeLabel.opacity = 150;

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

    CCLOG(@"Game Paused");
}
```

Also, most of my sprites come from sprite sheets. I don't know if that helps.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Wow... I have been looking for an answer for this for about a month and RIGHT after I ask this question I decide to search it again and... I find it.

Please excuse my stupidity...

```
CCLayerColor* colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 100)];
[self addChild:colorLayer z:0];
```

The first three numbers are "RBG" colors and the last number is opacity.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to put an overlay over everything and animate it's alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 and just choose the color white? Or black?

Comment: That's a good idea, but CCLayerColor works perfectly and can be easily hidden with "colorLayer.visible = NO;".  It also has the ability to change the opacity.

Comment: Ah I see, very good. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it for yourself in 24h.

Comment: I will. Thank you for your quick response in the beginning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put a color overlay on top of a layer just add..

```
CCLayerColor* colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 128)];
[self addChild:colorLayer z:0];
```

The first three numbers are "RGB" colors and the last number is opacity. Each can have a value in range between 0 and 255.

E.G.

```
layerWithColor:ccc4(Red, Green, Blue, Opacity)
```

Comment: +1 Simple yet effective. One cool thing about this trick is that you can exclude some sprites/nodes from getting the color tint by putting them in a layer that is on top of the CCLayerColor.